# Play Model M key sound on keypress

Tags: audio, keyboard

I love my dad's IBM model M keyboard. But I cannot use it as I use a laptop. I want the [custom click click sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Modelm.ogg) to be played when I press chiclet keys of lenovo laptop.

Can we add sound to key press in windows 7?

Comment: You actually _want_ a noisy keyboard!? Why don't you just connect your Dad's keyboard to your laptop?

Comment: it has PS 2 port. They don't put those port in laptop. Heck laptop  dosent even have a RS232 port!I will have to buy a PS2-usb converter. Also I dont want to carry the bulky keyboard around.

Comment: This might get you by until you find something that lets you customize the sound: https://www.grc.com/freeware/clickey.htm